# SAPUI5 - Data binding to existing XML Table

Tags: javascript, xml, data-binding, sapui5

I created a simple test table in Web IDE:

```
<Table id="testTable" class="navTableControlLayout" growing="true">     
            <headerToolbar id ="testTable_testToolbar">
                <Toolbar id="testToolbar">
                    <Label id="testTitle" text="{viewProperties>/catalogTitleText}" class="sapMH4FontSize" visible="{viewProperties>/catalogTitleVisible}" />
                    <ToolbarSpacer id="testSpacer" />
                </Toolbar>
            </headerToolbar>
</Table>
```

In my controller.js, I want to bind data to the table like this:

```
bindTable: function(){
    var oTable = this._oView.byId('testTable');
    var oTableModel = this._oComponent.getModel('IMF');
    oTable.setModel(oTableModel);
    oTable.bindRows('/FormHdrSet');
}
```

this._oView is the current view and the model is an oDataModel.

But I get an error:

```
uncaught typeError: bindRows is not a function
```

Any idea how this is possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your xmlns default declaration is `sap.m` and not `sap.ui.table`
sample would be:

```
<mvc:View
  height="100%"
  controllerName="sap.m.sample.Page"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m">
```

Looking at the aggregations of table, looks like you are using [sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Table.html)
What I mean to say is, `sap.m.Table` doesn't have any method called `bindRows`.
[Read more here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Table.html)

Nevertheless if you want to use `sap.ui.table.Table` control, then declare it in your xml. And then you can use [bindRows](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#bindRows) for the table

```
<mvc:View
  height="100%"
  controllerName="sap.m.sample.TableBreadcrumb.Page"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
  xmlns="sap.m">
```

and then your table would look like:

```
<table:Table id="testTable" >     
           ...
</table:Table>
```